# Create HTMLImageElement in web worker

Tags: javascript, opencv, web-worker

I am trying to use OpencvJs as a web worker.
but imread function of ovencvJs needs HTMLImageElement as a param.

```
opencv.imread(image);
```

in the main thread, I was creating with the following code:

```
function getImageElementFromUrl(imageUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = imageUrl;
      image.onload = () => {
        resolve(image);
      };
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

but in web worker, I am getting an error

```
ReferenceError: Image is not defined
```

can anyone please help me with how I can create HTMLImageElement in web worker or any other way to use opencv.imread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load an image that can be used in a Web Worker, you can use the [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) method, which will return a Promise resolving with an `ImageBitmap` object, which can be used by most consumers of `HTMLImageElement` objects.
However, to use *OpenCV* in a worker environment, it's not the only thing you need.
Weirdly enough, some of the code base already does handle a few things for worker environments, but they crash not long after that.
Among the things I noticed were needed to run [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/js_geometric_transformations_warpPerspective.html):

- `HTMLImageElement` they use it unsafely with `instanceof` so it needs to be defined. Since we're gonna use an `ImageBitmap` as source instead, we can define it to that.
- `HTMLCanvasElement` same as above. For this one, we can use the `OffscreenCanvas` constructor instead.
- `document.createElement("canvas")` For this particular example, this method is only called with `"canvas"` as argument, so we can override it easily with a function that returns an `OffscreenCanvas`.

Then we also needed to have a destination where *OpenCV* could render, and for this we use an `OffscreenCanvas` that we extracted from a `<canvas>` element.

```js
const workerScript = document.querySelector("[type=worker]").textContent;
const workerBlob = new Blob([workerScript], { type: "text/javascript" });
const workerURL = URL.createObjectURL(workerBlob);
const worker = new Worker(workerURL);

// Start by sending our destination canvas
const placeholder = document.querySelector("canvas");
const dest = placeholder.transferControlToOffscreen();
worker.postMessage(dest, [dest]);

// Then process the image
const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png";
worker.postMessage(url);
document.querySelector("img").src = url;

document.querySelector("input").onchange = ({ target: { files } }) => {
  worker.postMessage(files[0]);
  document.querySelector("img").src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
};
```

```css
canvas, img, video {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
.caption {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script type="worker">
/** We need to trick opencv in thinking we're in a normal web env. */
self.HTMLImageElement = ImageBitmap;
self.HTMLCanvasElement = OffscreenCanvas;
self.document = {
 createElement() {
  return new OffscreenCanvas(300, 150);
 }
};
/** So we now when ASM has done its job */
const cvReady = new Promise((res) => {
  self.Module = {
    onRuntimeInitialized() {
      res();
    }
  };
});
importScripts("https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/opencv.js");
importScripts("https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/utils.js");

async function fetchAsBlob(url) {
  const resp = await fetch(url);
  if (!resp.ok) { throw "Network Error"; }
  return resp.blob();
}
async function processImage(source, dest) {
  if (typeof source === "string") {
    source = await fetchAsBlob(source);
  }
  await cvReady;
  const inputBmp = await createImageBitmap(source);

  // Taken from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/js_geometric_transformations_warpPerspective.html
  let src = cv.imread(inputBmp);
  let dst = new cv.Mat();
  let dsize = new cv.Size(src.rows, src.cols);
  // (data32F[0], data32F[1]) is the first point
  // (data32F[2], data32F[3]) is the sescond point
  // (data32F[4], data32F[5]) is the third point
  // (data32F[6], data32F[7]) is the fourth point
  let srcTri = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [56, 65, 368, 52, 28, 387, 389, 390]);
  let dstTri = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 300, 300, 300]);
  let M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(srcTri, dstTri);
  // You can try more different parameters
  cv.warpPerspective(src, dst, M, dsize, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, new cv.Scalar());
  cv.imshow(dest, dst); /** edited  to pass our OffscreenCanvas */
  src.delete(); dst.delete(); M.delete(); srcTri.delete(); dstTri.delete();
  inputBmp.close(); // close the ImageBitmap
};
let dest = null;
onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  if (data instanceof OffscreenCanvas) {
    dest = data;
  }
  else {
    processImage(data, dest);
  }
};
</script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img>
      </td>
      <td>
        <canvas></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="caption">canvasInput <input type="file" accept="image/*"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="caption">canvasOutput</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```